# jmeter test plan for searching results from google

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am in attempt of creating a test plan which will search a string from Google let suppose search string is "**English alphabets**" In sampler I am using the following under Send parameters with requests

1) `Name = #q and Value = ${SearchString}` and I have declared search string under test plan global variables And *method* is `Get`.

2) Please note that google only uses get type methods for searching.

Simplified:

1) I am trying to create a test plan which search a string from google.

2) I am using firebug -> Network section to monitor Get and Post methods.

3) I found Google only uses get methods for it so

a) Then I analysis the google url it uses query string like

https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=software+testing

so I used two variables in http sampler , #q and value for the value section.

But it is not working.

Comment: What is the question ?